# ng-class not being applied to accordion header

Tags: html, css, asp.net, angularjs

I have a class defined that should turn the panel heading of an accordion control red. The class is defined as follows

```
.overridden .panel-heading {
    background-color: red;
}
```

When I specify this

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="kvp in jobTemplate.jobMasterConfigGroups[$index].jobMasterConfigs" is-open="kvp.active" class="overridden">
```

The heading background goes red for all rows, so it is picking up the class. However when I do

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="kvp in jobTemplate.jobMasterConfigGroups[$index].jobMasterConfigs" is-open="kvp.active" ng-class="{'overridden': 1 == 1}">
```

It doesn't change. I have hardcoded the expression to 1 == 1 to force a true evaluation just for testing (I will be using a variable later) but cannot even get it to display red on a hard coded true evaluation.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Update: I have tried

```
 <accordion-group ng-repeat="kvp in jobTemplate.jobMasterConfigGroups[$index].jobMasterConfigs" is-open="kvp.active" ng-class="{'overridden': 1 == 1}">
                                        <accordion-heading ng-class="{'overridden': kvp.isOverridden}">
                                            <div ng-class="{'overridden': kvp.isOverridden}">
                                                <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-minus': kvp.active, 'fa-plus': !kvp.active}"></i>
                                                <span>Key: <strong>{{kvp.Key | cut:false:15}}</strong> Value: <strong>{{kvp.value | cut:false:50}}</strong></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </accordion-heading>
```

Which makes the background red but only the background of the text, not the padding and the entire accordion header background. So I have proven my kvp.isOverridden works, as does the ng-class directive, however I can't seem to get the class to apply to the accordion-header, so I'm guessing I don't have the right CSS defined or am trying to override it at the wrong level. All of the accordion stuff seems to be in bootstrap.css so perhaps there's another style overriding what I'm trying to set? What CSS and override do I need to get the accordion-header control to be overridden?

Update 2: The following overrides the background for all panels in my website and works, obviously I want to only override it conditionally on this one block of code, but this confirms that it is the way I am applying styles or not overriding the default one that is the problem

```
.panel-default >.panel-heading {
    background-color: #5bc0de;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `accordion-heading` directive to provide custom class for heading

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="kvp in jobTemplate.jobMasterConfigGroups[$index].jobMasterConfigs" 
 is-open="kvp.active">
    <accordion-heading>
        <i ng-class="{'overridden': 1 === 1}"></i> My Heading
    </accordion-heading>
    This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
</accordion-group>
```